# Error while plotting PyMC model using pymc.Matplot

Tags: pymc, matplotlib

I am getting an error while plotting PyMC model using pymc.Matplot after a successful fit

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import pylab
import pymc as pm
import numpy as np

import seir as mod
reload(mod) 

mc = pm.MCMC(mod)
mc.use_step_method(pm.AdaptiveMetropolis, [mod.beta, mod.gamma, mod.s0, mod.eF, mod.i0])
mc.sample(iter = 1000000, burn = 200000, thin = 500, verbose = 1)

Plotting eF

￼
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-31405478c9cb>", line 1, in <module>
    pm.Matplot.plot(mc)

  File "C:\Users\tele\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymc\Matplot.py", line 341, in wrapper
    f(data, name, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\tele\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymc\Matplot.py", line 455, in plot
    fontmap=fontmap)

  File "C:\Users\tele\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymc\Matplot.py", line 377, in wrapper
    f(pymc_obj, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\tele\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymc\Matplot.py", line 578, in histogram
    hist(data.tolist(), bins, histtype='stepfilled')

  File "C:\Users\tele\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2958, in hist
    stacked=stacked, data=data, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\tele\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1810, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\tele\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5995, in hist
    m, bins = np.histogram(x[i], bins, weights=w[i], **hist_kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\tele\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 249, in histogram
    n += np.bincount(indices, weights=tmp_w, minlength=bins).astype(ntype)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (11,) (12,) (11,)
```

The error arises in some situation but not always. Since this is an internal function of pyMC and the fit works (actually is very good), I am not sure what to do (BTW, I usually find another error (not sure if related) while calling `scores = pm.geweke(mc, intervals=20)` with the same model).

Answer (score 0):

Just found the error, silly problem with decimating the numpy array: pyMC crashes because the sizes of the mean (simulated) and observed values of the random variable representing the likelihood aren't the same. The error provided by pyMC is not very expressive btw.